# Can I install double breaker in place of single breaker?

Tags: electrical, dryer

In my electric box I have only one space for single beaker. Can I install double beaker 30amp in that place? Or I have to change all electric box?
I would like to use electric dryer.

Comment: Likely not, but without pictures of the situation, can't tell you for sure. Detailed, in focus pictures of your breaker box can lead to a good deal of possible options to work around this, but they depend on what it is, and what's in it now. Please [edit] the question to add some.

Comment: You need two places for a double breaker.  Add pictures of your panel with the labels of what is allowed in it.  Might be probably to have some half/tandem breakers to free up space or add a sub panel for more circuit/breaker space.

Comment: But OP would need 2 places for the circuit breaker to the new sub panel, right?  Which he doesn't have room for.

Comment: @SteveSh   A sub panel will take some circuits from the main panel, so there will be enough spaces.  Just moving the circuits around.

Comment: Can you post photos of your existing breaker panel please?